# Make the Information part better in a cat profile

Tags: website-design, design, mobile-web

Hello guys im creating a site for a cat breeding company. The site is 95% users on mobile web browsers. How can I make the Information section more beautiful. Do you see any other things I could change on the page?

[image: Profile page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Increase the contrast on your greys (darker text).
- Probably don't italicize the main title.
- Use some iconography for easier visual skimming. ♂️ Male, etc. (Ideally an icon font rather than emojis since the latter will look different on different devices.)
- Avoid unnecessary labels for data if possible. Words like "male" and "fertile", especially when supported with icons, are self-explanatory without a category word. In other words, instead of "Fertile: Yes", just " Fertile" or "❄️ Infertile". You can always keep the information via title text or more accessible tooltip-style things, e.g. a little  that when you hover or click on it shows text like

> <sub>*This cat is fertile. It can contribute DNA to kittens.*</sub>

- Where you do have categories, differentiate them in the typography. That can be through bold, underline, italicize, capitalize, font choice, font size, etc. Or it can be through spacing — I particularly like to use a single width for my labels for a cleaner look. (This can contradict the above about dropping labels; you'll have to play around to find out what looks best.)

A couple of hasty mockups to get you thinking...

[image: mockups]